# Avoid CSS prettify creates new line for each tag on sublime 3

Tags: html, css, sublimetext3, prettify

I'm using HTML - CSS - JS Prettify Plugin and sometimes when I write CSS styles I like to put them next to the other, like this

`h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .uk-h1, .uk-h3, .uk-h4, .uk-h5, .uk-h6`

but when I prettify the file it puts each tag below the previous one turning this into a 11-lines tall segment. Is there a way to tell the plugin to  avoid this kind of behavior?

Comment: yes... https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify

Comment: I saw the .jsbeautifyrc config before but I don't know how should I edit it to have this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Find where your Prettify lives in your menu and look for `Set Prettify Preferences`.

Then find this line and make sure its set to false.

```
"newline_between_rules": false, // Add a new line after every css rule
```